# How to merge 3 defferent comparative dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have 3 seperate data frames which are; **close_price_df**, **returns_df** and **volume_df** of multiple symbols in comparison. I would like to merge them in order of **close_price_df**, **returns_df** and **volume_df**. How can I achieve that?.

Here are the data frames;

[image]

[image]

[image]

My expected result should be like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `pd.concat(close_price_df, returns_df, volume_df)`?

Comment: Hi dcsuka, thanks for your time. I did but got an error **TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"**

Comment: I fixed it up but no any indication of where returns or volume starts

Comment: Why not just add a column for each of them with their names and then merge?

Comment: @JamiuShaibu i guess the error - `TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame" ` is because of the missing square brackets.

try this `pd.concat([close_price_df, returns_df, volume_df])`

Comment: if you are still facing the issue, update the question with the code and the error you are facing

Comment: The error was resolved but the output did not meet my expected result. Thanks for your time, I just updated my question and added how my expected result should look like. Maybe you can refer to the question again to see if you have any idea of working around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.concat()`

```py
pd.concat([close_price_df, returns_df, volume_df], axis=1)
```

**Edit:**

Since 3 dataframes that merged all have the same columns, the column name for each df better be prefixed first to avoid some problem.

```py
close_price_df.columns= ['close_price_'+i for i in close_price_df.columns]
returns_df.columns= ['returns_'+i for i in returns_df.columns]
volume_df.columns= ['volume_'+i for i in volume_df.columns]
```

Comment: Hi zousan! Thanks for your time, that didn't solve my problem, I just updated my question and added how my expected results should look like. Maybe you can refer to the question again to see if you have any idea of working around that.

Comment: So you wanted to merge it horizontally, you can do that by simply change the `axis` argument with `1`.

Comment: That worked zousan

Comment: @JamiuShaibu Glad to hear it!